# Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime in VS2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc

when I want to load data from my mysql database I always get this error:

> Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime

This is my connectionstring:

```
<add name="gdmwebsiteEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DBModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DBModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;User Id=root;database=gdmwebsite&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I've already added "Convert Zero Datetime=True" add the end of my connectionstring but nothing changed.

```
    <add name="gdmwebsiteEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DBModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DBModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;User Id=root;database=gdmwebsite&quot;
     Convert Zero Datetime=True
      Allow Zero Datetime=True"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Is there another method for fixing this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set both of these configurations in your connection string.

```
"Convert Zero Datetime=True"
"Allow Zero Datetime=True"
```

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26054

> Please check manual under connect options and set "Allow Zero
>   Datetime" to true, as on attached pictures, and the error will go
>   away.

Check this also: http://mdid.org/mdidwiki/index.php?title=Unable_to_convert_MySQL_date/time_value_to_System.DateTime_exception

> To fix this problem, **either replace all invalid timestamps with NULL
>   or a valid timestamp, or add Allow Zero Datetime=true**

Comment: Changed it, but then I get a Configuration Error. Am I doing it right? (edited my begin post)

Comment: @niels123 Check this also http://www.ironspeed.com/Designer/10.0.1/WebHelp/Part_VI/Unable_to_convert_MySQL_date_time_value_to_System_DateTime.htm `Make sure that date columns in the MySQL database either contains all valid values or contain NULL.`