# IsDBNull throws an exception

Tags: c#

I'm reading MySql database where one the columns is of DateTime type. Some of these dates are null. I can't seem to figure out how to check if value is null or not.
I thought that IsDbNull would solve the problem, but it makes no difference at all

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(4))
{
   service.ServiceDate = reader.GetDateTime("serviceDate");
}
```

This is the exception I'm getting:

> "Additional information: Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to
>   System.DateTime"

I also tried

```
if (System.DBNull.Value == reader.IsDBNull(4))
```

as well as

```
reader.IsDBNull(4).ToString()
```

and

```
Convert.ToBoolean(reader.IsDBNull(4))
```

How do I check for it without using try catch?

Comment: What is the type of reader?

Comment: What is the datetime value that you're reading? It may be outside the range of System.DateTime.

Comment: `IsDBNull` doesn't throw that error. But `reader.GetDateTime("serviceDate")` should cause a compiler error since `GetDateTime` only accepts an `int` as parameter which is the index of the column. Show your real code.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002522/unable-to-convert-mysql-date-time-value-to-system-datetime-in-vs2010

Comment: Blorgbeard, GetDateTime has a string overload and it was IsDBNull that was throwing an error. I made sure of it by trying to check out it's results via immediate window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error does not seem to have anything to do with IsDBNull - it specifically mentions the DateTime conversion. Have you tried passing the column index to `GetDateTime`, just as you are doing with `IsDbNull`?

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(4))
{
   service.ServiceDate = reader.GetDateTime(4);
}
```

.

**Another Possibility: `Convert Zero Datetime=true`**

Additionally, after reading some other info on the error, it sounds like you may need to add `Convert Zero Datetime=true` to your connection string, which enables the conversion of `0000-00-00 00:00:00` values in a `DATETIME` column (if you have any of those) to `DateTime.MinValue`.

Check out some of the results here: http://www.bing.com/search?q=Unable+to+convert+MySQL+date%2Ftime+value+to+System.DateTime&form=IE10TR&src=IE10TR&pc=HPDTDFJS