# Datatable LINQ query throws exception for datetime column

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

```
for (DateTime date = fromDate; date <= toDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
   var bwSalesValue = (from r in dtSalesData.AsEnumerable()
                       where r.Field<int>("PositionId") == pdPositionId 
                       && r.Field<DateTime>("SaleDate") == date
                       select r.Field<int>("SaleValue")).FirstOrDefault();


}
```

From the above snippet `r.Field<DateTime>("SaleDate") == date` part throws exception **Specified cast is not valid**.

date variable and dtSalesData rows have the same value `3/1/2015 12:00:00 AM`

Any clue?

UPDATE==================================

Sorry friends, I did a silly mistake here. Problem is in the next line-

```
select r.Field<int>("SaleValue")).FirstOrDefault(); //Would be <decimal>
```

Please accept my apology. Thanks to all.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002522/unable-to-convert-mysql-date-time-value-to-system-datetime-in-vs2010). May be a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this?

```
var bwSalesValue = (from r in dtSalesData.AsEnumerable()
                   where r.Field<int>("PositionId") == pdPositionId 
                   && Convert.ToDateTime(r.SaleDate) == date
                   select r.Field<int>("SaleValue")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (DateTime date = fromDate; date <= toDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
   var bwSalesValue = (from r in dtSalesData.AsEnumerable()
                       where r.Field<int>("PositionId") == pdPositionId 
                       && r.Field<DateTime>("SaleDate") == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue : date);
                       select r.Field<int>("SaleValue")).FirstOrDefault();


}
```

Maybe you shouldnt use where clause when SaleDate return `DBNull.Value` because it can't be convert DateTime to null.