# Converting and comparing mysql and c# datetime

Tags: c#, mysql

Hi there is an program I'm working on and in the diary section I'm having some problems.

while registering the entries I'm using the following code where appdate is the appointment date.
dtpappdate is my datetimepicker.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?appdate", dtpappdate.Value.ToShortDateString());
```

the above code works fine and when I make entries. It successfully stores the date into the mysql database.

then When I read from database I want to compare the dates of the entries in the database and my current date on the computer so that it will only display the matched dates to display my to do list.

the following is the code to read and compare but my program gives me an error. telling me I fail converting the data.

```
DateTime dn = new DateTime();
        dn = DateTime.Now;

        string constring = "Server=localhost;Database=vetsoft; uid=root;pwd=geyikler88;";
        string command = "SELECT * FROM vetsoft.clients ";

        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection myCon = new MySqlConnection(constring))
            {
               using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(command, myCon))
              {
                  myCon.Open();

                  MySqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                  while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    if( Convert.ToDateTime( myReader["appdate"].ToString()) == dn)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add("İsim: " + myReader["name"].ToString() + " Telefon: " + myReader["phone"].ToString() + " P İsim: " + myReader["pname"].ToString() + " Yaş: " + myReader["age"].ToString() + " Randevu Saati: " + myReader["apptime"].ToString() + " Hastalık: " + myReader["sickness"].ToString() + " Ek Not: " + myReader["eknot"].ToString());

                    }
                }
```

How can I correctly make the comparison? any help?

Comment: What is the error exactly? On which line? What is your variables? And why do you keep your `DateTime` values with their string representations? This is a bad approach. Use your `dtpappdate.Value` when you insert your value, not string representation.

Comment: Why are you using strings at all? If it's a date in the database, just use `DateTime` everywhere. Don't call `ToShortDateString` on `dtappdate.Value`. Cast `myReader["appdate"]` to `DateTime` instead of converting it to a string and back.

Comment: Additional information: Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime this is the error I get

Comment: I get the error at the if statement

Comment: Maybe related? http://stackoverflow.com/q/17002522/447156

Answer (score 0):

You compare that C#'s DateTime.Now == the datetime from the MySQL database.  This is unlikely to EVER be true, except by pure dumb luck, since DateTime.Now includes the current time down to the tick.

Presuming you are only interested in matching by date, use DateTime.Today to compare, but the date value in your MySQL database should also be date, so you will need to strip time off of that if you are storing time.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't convert dates to string for comparing. If you only want to compare date part of datetime, use Date property, ex:

```
var appDate = myReader["appdate"] as Datetime;
if (appDate.Date == Datetime.Now.Date) {
    // Your code goes here
}
```

It's also good practice to keep dates in db in UTC. This way you don't have to worry about timezones and summer saving time.